# Вакансия для Java junior или стажировка

Tags: java

Вопрос может немного не для этого сообщества, но все же....
Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую компанию следует устраиваться на работу человеку, не имеющего реального опыта , но имеющего базовые знания по Java (алгоритмы, структуры данных, базовые паттерны). И где условия труда приемлемые (это не про высокую зарплату, а про реальную трудовую практику и нормальное отношение в колоективе). Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

Comment: Поэтому я и извинился, всё-таки новичок ещё, не совсем разбираюсь что и куда писать)

Comment: К сожалению, факт извинения никаких преференций не дает.

Answer (score 3):

1. Везде хорошо, где нас нет.
2. Ищите компании, в которых нет 100% осадки кадров или наоборот 100% ухода сотрудников *(Типа Acronis)*
3. Ищите компании, где нет ваших друзей (жизненный совет)
4. Избегайте новые мелкие или старые большие компании (я сейчас не про компании гиганты)
5. Ходите на курсы
6. Избегайте НИИ
7. Сарафанное радио вам поможет, но не забывайте п.1

Comment: P.S. Вам лучше в чаты и форумы, а не на сайт взаимопомощи кодом

Comment: п.1 Везде хорошо, где нас нет. [Там, где нас нет, может быть еще хуже](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7j9X2gAzRxs)

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh это фразеологизм. Означает, что пока человек сам на себе не почувствует, не видит минусов (или не хочет видеть их) - там где-то далеко место кажется очень хорошим. А как окунется в, простите за выражение, все это дерьмо - сразу понимает насколько оно плохо, и начинает смотреть новое место. И снова - у попа была собака, он ее любил...